# Kafka Producer Slows down when putting different keys

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a code that will send data to Kafka topic.

```
public void sendMessage(String message, String key){
   if (isAsync) { // Send asynchronously
       producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic,key,message), new ProducerCallback(key, message));
   } else { // Send synchronously
       try {
           producer.send(new ProducerRecord(topic,key, message)).get();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           // handle the exception
       }

   }
```

}

I am passing the data to the method using the code below:

```
String Message ="Text message,Text message,Text message,Text message,Text message,Text message,Text message,Text message,Text message,Text message";
String Key = "0123456789";

for(int i =0; i < 10000; i++)
{
   publish.sendMessage(Message, Key);
}
```

Since the Message and Key are static, the code sends data to Kafka with low latency (less than 1 second for 10K records) but if I will have a dynamic key, the performance slows down (almost 55 seconds for 10K records). Code will be

```
for(int i =0; i < 10000; i++)
{
   publish.sendMessage(Message, Key+i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each iteration, `Key+i` involves instantiating, initializing a new StringBuilder object and calling its `append` and `toString` method which can indeed slow down the entire process.

Comment: Im measuring the performance in the `sendMessage()` method, so the `stringBuilder` doesn't affect the performance.